# Capture events of other installer file like Notepad++ setup in Inno Setup

Tags: windows-installer, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to execute an executable file (`npp.exe`) before installation begins in Inno Setup. But I am not able to capture the nextButton event of the `npp.exe` executable. Is there any way to do it? I tried with following code:

```pascal
function initializeSetup(): boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
  path: string;
begin
   if Exec(('C:\Users\Paxcel\Downloads\npp.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
       ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
       //result code = 0 for successful installation
       if (ResultCode = 0)then
          begin
              Result := True;
          end
          else
          begin
              Result := False;
          end;
    // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
     end
     else begin
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode),mbError,MB_OK);
        Result := False;// handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code
     end;
   end;
```

In this code, I want to capture the next button of Notepad++ setup. Default functions like `NextButtonClick` cannot be used.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl By nextButton event of npp.exe file, he means the 'Next' button that appears on the setup wizard window that is intended to move to next step of the installation.

Comment: Typically it is not sensible to do this.  Instead you should run the Notepad++ installer silently, supplying any options that it requires via the command line or a response file.  Before you do either of those things, of course, you also need to check that you're actually allowed to repackage Notepad++ by its creators.

Answer (score 2):

The Notepad++ uses NSIS installer.

If you want to run (any) NSIS installer silently, use `/S` command-line switch.

See [NSIS Installer usage](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusagecommon).

---

Btw, I assume that the path `C:\Users\Paxcel\Downloads` is just for testing. In a real installer, you have to embed the dependency to your installer and extract it to a temporary directory to execute it.

Inno Setup can do this all for you, you typically do not need to code this yourself using Pascal Scripting.

```
[Run]
Source: "path\npp.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\npp.exe"; Parameters: "/S"
```

Comment: yes that path is for testing only. and thank you for response but  i donot get my answer. my que is how i handle the next button in installation wizard of notepad setup?? actually i want some action to perform when user click on next button of installation wizard. Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Well everything is possible, but this is very tricky. I do not even think this would be possible in Inno Setup Pascal scripting. You would probably have to implement plugin .dll. Consider asking more specific question, describing what kind of action you want to trigger and why. Btw, it would probably be a way easier to implement a new custom installer for Notepad++ than trying to hack the existing one.